Do I need to repeat the license text if one library is licensed under multiple licenses and another library uses just one of those licenses?
I’m combining all third-party licenses and notices into a single LICENSE.txt and summarizing them in a single NOTICE.txt file
Library A is licensed only under Apache License Version 2.0.
Library B is licensed under both Apache License Version 2.0.
and another license (e.g., ObjectStyle License).
Do I need to repeat the full text of the Apache License Version 2.0. in the LICENSE.txt file for both libraries? Or can I include it once and just reference both libraries in the NOTICE.txt file?
What is the proper way to handle this situation to stay compliant with license requirements?

Could you take a look at How to combine multiple LICENSE notes into single file and let us know whether it answers your question, and if not, what remains unanswered?

@MadHatter Thank you, now I have update the question.

As you've now asked multiple similar questions on this site (some now deleted) and haven't responded to the request for clarification, I'll answer the questions as written:

Do I need to repeat the full text of the Apache License Version 2.0. in the LICENSE.txt file for both libraries?

No, you do not. The Apache license makes no reference to a LICENSE.txt file, so there is no requirement for that file to exist at all.

Or can I include it once and just reference both libraries in the NOTICE.txt file?

The requirement is that in section 4(a) of the license: "You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License". It is not specified how you do that.
The Apache license section 4(d) does have very specific requirements about the contents of a NOTICE text file (which is subtly different from a NOTICE.txt file). You should ensure you read, understand and follow those requirements.
Stepping back here, you seem to be attempting to do open source compliance by examining other open source projects and attempting to "reverse engineer" the requirements. I strongly suggest you stop doing that and actually read the licenses instead, because otherwise you will get it wrong.

+10 if I could, for that last paragraph.

@Philip Kendall I read the license, but I don’t fully understand Section 4(d) regarding attribution notices, which seems to focus mostly on derivative works.
